# Почему умирает процесс задачи в очереди Laravel?

Tags: php, ubuntu, очередь, laravel5

ОС Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Есть скрипт, который я запускаю фоном через очереди Laravel.

Через какое-то время пишет - "Убито". 
Если запускать скрипт не фоном, то отрабатывает без ошибок. 
На Windows такого не происходит.

[image: kill]

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорей всего - нехватка свободной оперативной памяти. Ваш скрипт очень быстро "съедает" её всю, и ядро вынужденно убить процесс с наименьшим приоритетом - коим ваш скрипт по счастливой случайности и является, т.к. запущен в в фоне.

Посмотрите на последние сообщения через `dmesg` - скорей всего в "момент смерти" там появится строчка вроде:

> Out of memory: Kill process 12345 (php) score 678 or sacrifice child

Если это действительно так, то у вас только два выбора - либо увеличивать ресурсы сервера, либо заняться оптимизацией своего кода.

Comment: Последнее сообщение - "ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush" - о чём это может говорить?

Answer (score 0):

проблема не нова, кажется, проблема с драйверами на wi-fi адаптер. Навскидку: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2210322 
https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-hardware/10585882
чип, как я догадываюсь, Ralink.